# How do I replace all occurences of a string on each line?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to replace all the occurences of the "username" by, let's say "+" ,  in the following script but it replaces only the first occurence

```
ls -al | sed 's/username/+/'
```

This is how sed works by default?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the `g` (global) modifier:

```
sed 's/username/+/g'
```

Comment: I just read something about g but I tought it must be used as parameter: like -g. Thanks a lot